# Absolute positioning on two overlapping html images while STILL being able to click?

Tags: javascript, html, css, position, css-position

So, I have two images I want to position over each other. Back image goes in the back, center image goes on top of it, and a random link (in this case google.com) goes on top of a specific drawn blue box on the center image.

I want to use absolute positioning so that the random link stays on the exact same part of the image. The reason the center image is separated from the back image is that later I want to do parallax scrolling where the background scrolls slower than the foreground. Also I'm going to add one more layer even further back later when I do the parallax thing, but for right now I'm just doing two.

This is the code that I have:

```
<div style="position: relative; pointer-events: none">
        <img src="/static/CenterImage.png" style="width: 100%; height: auto; z-index:5; position: absolute; pointer-events: none;">
        <img src="/static/BackImage.png" style="width: 100%; height: auto; position:absolute; z-index:4; pointer-events: none; ">
        <a href="www.google.com" title="gg" style="position: absolute; left: 39.75%; top: 15.93%; width: 25.75%; height: 8.64%; pointer-events: all; z-index: 6;"></a>
</div>
```

I for the life of me, cannot click that bottom link. When I delete position:absolute in the top image, suddenly I can no longer see the back image, but I can now perfectly click the link on the blue box.

How do I do this :(

Comment: This is a stacking issue in terms of z-index. As indicated by the first answer you can place the point-event to none. I suggest looking up here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events#values

Comment: So what do you need ,???

Comment: But I tried that already and nothing happened, I have pointer-events:none for the images and tried pointer-events:all and auto for the link, I also tried all combinations of pointer-events:all auto and none for the parent div too

Answer (score 0):

you can put

```
pointer-events: none;
```

to styles of your elements/images that you don't want to be clickable and block the proper link

Comment: I tried this in my code above and it didn't work :(

Comment: can you show code for that? current snippet has `pointer-events: none` on whole div wrapper

Comment: I tried it without the parent wrapper having pointer-events:none. The same exact code except that line deleted.

Comment: it does work, link is clickable, check the code https://jsfiddle.net/fp857k1y/9/

Comment: Also you have nothing in your <a> tag, put some text or img in there like in my example (link) so you can click on anything to direct you to google.com